# importing NER json into spaCy

Tags: json, spacy, spacy-3

I am trying to import my NER data into spaCy. I have it in a json format, which I made thinking this was what spaCy required. My goal is to train an entity recognition system the recognises a custom set of entities.
Below is a small example of the data I am using.

```
test =[{'datapoint_id': 0,
  'text': 'westleigh lodge care home, nel pan lane, leigh (wn7 5jt)',
  'entities': [[0, 25, 'building_name'],
   [27, 39, 'street_name'],
   [41, 46, 'city'],
   [48, 55, 'postcode']]},
{'datapoint_id': 1,
  'text': 'land at 2a gerard street, ashton in makerfield, wigan (wn4 9aa)',
  'entities': [(0, 4, 'unit_type'),
   (11, 24, 'street_name'),
   (48, 53, 'city'),
   (55, 62, 'postcode')]},
 {'datapoint_id': 2,
  'text': 'unit 111, timber wharf, worsley street, manchester (m15 4nz)',
  'entities': [(0, 4, 'unit_type'),
   (5, 8, 'unit_id'),
   (10, 23, 'building_name'),
   (24, 38, 'street_name'),
   (40, 50, 'city'),
   (52, 59, 'postcode')]}]
```

The spacy introduction course https://course.spacy.io/en gives guides on how to turn individual examples into spacy format but not large amounts of data.

Calling `nlp(test[0])` causes an 'Expected a string or 'Doc' as input, but got: <class 'dict'>.' error

Calling `!python -m spacy convert "/home/test.json" "/home/ouput/"` produces a 'KeyError: 'paragraphs' error.

I can do

```
doc = nlp(test[0]['text'])
gold_dict = test[0]['entities']
example = Example.from_dict(doc, {'entities':gold_dict})

example
```

and loop through creating a list of examples, but it doesn't seem like the right approach and I am not sure what to do with the list of results.

I tried doing

```
corpus = JsonlCorpus("/home/test.json")
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
data = corpus(nlp)
doc_bin = DocBin(docs=data)
```

But this did not seem to load or save the dataset.

Obviously loading data must be very straight foreword, but I can't do it, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For training data spaCy just requires Docs that are set like the output you want, saved in a DocBin. So for your case, looping through your data and creating Docs is the right thing to do. You can do that with your Example-creating code and pull out the `ex.reference` Doc (an Example is basically just two Docs, one annotated and one not), though it's not the only way.

See [the sample code](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data) in the training data section of the docs. It's not exactly the same format as your data but it's very similar.

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
training_data = [
  ("Tokyo Tower is 333m tall.", [(0, 11, "BUILDING")]),
]
# the DocBin will store the example documents
db = DocBin()
for text, annotations in training_data:
    doc = nlp(text)
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annotations:
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
        ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents
    db.add(doc)
db.to_disk("./train.spacy")
```